# In the wordpress admin area, how to deregister default styles?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, stylesheet

What are the handles to the default stylesheets in the admin area so I can deregister the ones I want?  Naturally I'll copy the styles over to my own stylesheet that are essential for the structure and basic styling.

Answer (score 3):

Not that many people will need this, but I'm styling the admin area heavily and trying to overwrite all the default styles is creating havoc in my stylesheets.

*(PS deregistering admin scripts is similary, but you have to make sure they don't get combined when printed.  I'll post that in another Q&A later. )*

So after some digging, I found the global $wp_styles.

After dumping it, I found tons of info, and in the depths, the handle to each style.  From there, I could deregister the necessary ones. Below is the debugging code I used to find the handles, then a couple examples of the deregistered styles.

```
global $wp_styles;
echo var_dump($wp_styles);
```

Then to print just the handles.  Uncomment the one line to print them neatly, or as here, it'll put them in a list that you can copy and past into the deregister function.

```
    global $wp_styles;

    foreach($wp_styles as $main_obj => $vals){
    if(is_array($vals)){
        // echo var_dump($vals);
        foreach($vals as $name => $obj){
            if(!empty($obj->handle)){
                // echo $obj->handle, '<br />';
                echo '"'.$obj->handle. '", ';
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

I know there's probably a few styles from plugins here here, but here's all the scripts enqueued in the admin area, just remove the appropriate ones from the array/function, add it within a hook, and all the styles will be gone (not advised, but pick and choose from there).

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'remove_admin_styles' );
function remove_admin_styles(){
    wp_deregister_style(
    'wp-admin',
    'ie',
    'colors',
    'colors-fresh',
    'colors-classic',
    'media',
    'install',
    'thickbox',
    'farbtastic',
    'jcrop',
    'imgareaselect',
    'admin-bar',
    'wp-jquery-ui-dialog',
    'editor-buttons',
    'wp-pointer',
    'jquery-listfilterizer',
    'jquery-ui-smoothness',
    'tooltips',
    );
    }
```

Comment: In order to print the style handles, you might as well use `print_r(wp_print_styles());`