# Disabling load-styles.php file in Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I want to override the Wordpress admin style for forms in my plugin. I would like to exclude the load-styles.php forms file. I tried to deregister the file by wp_deregister_style('wp-admin'); but this doesn't work.

I would really appreciate any help if you know how to deregister the file.

Thanks!

Comment: Just wanted to suggest another option, add a CSS file specifically for your plugin that overrides the admin styles. That way any other code that may need the `load-styles.php` functionality doesn't have it taken away.

Comment: Hello
I think the solution is here Take a look at it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12795689/in-the-wordpress-admin-area-how-to-deregister-default-styles

Comment: treckstar the problem of the css is that the selector is directly on the element itself. which means that i need to add "!importants" to the css of the template. that i am using.  But if i can just turn off the css wordpress adds for the admin forms that would be just awesome but difficult somehow

MortezaBarati i tried that too but i there is no form styling css between those sadly

Answer (score 0):

You can remove default admin style  with "admin_init" hook

```
   function remove_default_admin_stylesheets() {
     wp_deregister_style('wp-admin');
   }

   add_action('admin_init','remove_default_admin_stylesheets');
```

It will work.

Comment: This doesn't work. It removes almost all the admin css that wordpress adds. I just want to remove the styling they add for forms as that is overwriting the css of my plugin

Comment: If you want to only remove css which is overriding your css plugin. You need to increase priority of your css so that your css call before admin css. Thus your problem will be solved.